# How to Generate Graphs using Python Panda

Tags: python, graph, ipython

I am very beginner in python and i am learning ipython notebook. I am able to read excel file but i did not able to draw graphs from excel file.!

Image : http://s15.postimg.org/wvo4zlsx7/Untitled.png

Can you give me reference or code where i can learn python panda graphs.

Comment: http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/visualization.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could also consider using pandas to read the sheets, and matplotlib to display graphs. http://matplotlib.org/gallery.html